# What are the parts of a time signature called?

Tags: notation, time-signatures

I'm wondering what the top and bottom numbers in a time signature are called. In math, the top number and bottom number in a fraction have specific names (numerator and denominator, respectively)—are there names for the top and bottom numbers of a time signature?

Comment: Hi KSchank. It seems like we have already answered this question, so I closed it as a duplicate. If the duplicate does not answer your question, please edit your question to reflect the difference.